# What API to interact with Admin Gmail "Recipient address map"?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

What is the Google API that will allow me to interact with Admin Gmail Advanced settings?

Right now, I'm interested in editing the **Recipient address map**.

In the Google Admin site, it's located at
`Apps > G Suite > Settings for Gmail > Advanced settings > General Settings > Recipient address map`

Answer (score 1):

Gmail general settings are no more reachable from the Gmail API. In the [Email Settings API migration guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings?hl=en#managing_general_settings) it is typed «*General settings are no longer available via the API*». You could [create an Issue Tracker feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui#create_an_issue) about mapping incoming mail addresses.

Comment: Feature requested as suggested: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180915825